# Splitviewcontroller logic is not right, duplicate content

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am trying to port my iphone app to Ipad, the logic does not work with `splitviewcontroller`.

In `viewDidLoad` i call a function that updates the view and with `setSearchResult` (overriding the setters)

the problem is everytime when i select a row in the `masterviewcontroller` the contents of the `detailviewcontroller` get added to it instead of removing the old contents..

i think this gives me the problem:

```
        CGRect framephoto = CGRectMake(0, 85, 320, 186);
        carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:framephoto];
        [self.scrollview addSubview:carousel];
```

and this table (custom mg)

```
    // the tables grid
    CGSize tablesGridSize = IPAD_TABLES_GRID;
    tablesGrid = [MGBox boxWithSize:tablesGridSize];
    tablesGrid.contentLayoutMode = MGLayoutGridStyle;
    [self.scrollview.boxes addObject:tablesGrid];
```

I think because everytime when i select a row and it gets to these codes it adds another one.

I am not a pro so maybe this question is stupid, but every tip is welcome..
Whats the best way to handle this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best way to handle this is to use the UINavigationController you should already have  in use in your application. A easy solution for your problem is to just remove all subviews before you are adding new ones (maybe you have to safe the references to the `iCarousel` and the `tablesGrid` for this). A even better way is to just update the data of the views you already have allocated.

Comment: @blauescocke i am removing the subview and tablesgrid in viewDidLoad at start.